# Wildcard symbol in Makefile executing some targets but not others

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

From what I've been able to find, the wildcard symbol in a Makefile target : prerequisite line is a pattern rule that states "for every target X.o, if there exists a file named X.c (for example), do the following commands"

What I can't seem to figure out is why, in the Makefile below only one of the wildcard arguments is executed.

```
all : foo.o

%.o : %.c
    echo first %.o : %.c

%.o : %.c
    echo second %.o : %.c

foo.o: foo.c foo.h bar.h baz.h
```

When I run all, I get this output:

```
echo second %.o : %.c
second %.o : %.c
```

According to what I know, both wildcard statements should be displayed, as they both match the pattern.  Can anyone explain why they aren't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second `%.o: %.c` rule **overrides** the first one. That is why output for the first rule is not output.

From the gnu-make [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canceling-Rules.html#Canceling-Rules):

> You can override a built-in implicit rule (or one you have defined yourself) by defining a new pattern rule with the same target and prerequisites, but a different recipe.

Comment: Thank you so much! Quick follow up question:  If I add a command to the final rule "foo.o: foo.c foo.h bar.h baz.h" that command will print, however leaving it blank makes the second to command execute.  Is this because without a command the rule doesn't get overridden, or some other reason?

Comment: `Is this because without a command the rule doesn't get overridden` - a rule without commands (*receipts* in make terminology) just introduces **additional dependencies**, but do not prevent receipts in other suitable rules to be executed. With receipt(s) (even with simple `;`), rule compete with others, and one with *more specific match* wins. That is, *normal* rule wins *pattern* one.